# syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Tags: git

Изучаю Git ([link text](http://githowto.com/ru/git_internals_git_directory)) и натолкнулся на такую команду:

```
ls -C .git/objects/<dir>
```

и когда ввел ее в GitBash, то получил такую ошибку:

*sh: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'*

Обыскал весь Инет, не могу найти, как ее устранить. Единственное, что понял, что проблема содержится в "<>". Видимо, Git Bash не понимает скобки.

Comment: > Видимо, Git Bash не понимает скобки.

`>` и `<` - стандартные операторы управления выводом и вводом. А под `<dir>` в мануале подразумевается произвольная папка, для того скобками и выделено.

Comment: @Etki, вот опять, прекрасный ответ. Отчего же он комментарием? =)

Comment: @sergiks, потому что в нем нет подробного разбора операторов и того, что описано в мануале. Я за то, чтобы ответы по содержанию были как ответы на so, на которые гугл выводит по банальным вопросам.

Comment: @Etki, своим ответом вы не лишаете возможности других написать более развернутый. Ваш комментарий, на мой взгляд, удовлетворяет требованию minimum viable answer, скажем так (по аналогии с [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product)) – позволяет застрявшему ТС сделать следующий шаг.

Answer (score 2):

ответ из комментария:

Видимо, Git Bash не понимает скобки. `>` и `<` - стандартные операторы управления выводом и вводом. А под `<dir>` в мануале подразумевается произвольная папка, для того скобками и выделено.

Comment: gitbash понимает угловые скобки так же, как и bash. Можете попробовать эту команду выполнить в нормальном bash, получите такой же результат. Просто угловая скобка в конце строки - ошибка синтаксиса.