# sh: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Tags: git

Изучаю Git (link text) и натолкнулся на такую команду:

```
ls -C .git/objects/<dir>
```

и когда ввел ее в GitBash, то получил такую ошибку:

```
sh: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

Обыскал весь Инет, не могу найти, как ее устранить. Единственное, что понял, что проблема содержится в "<>". Видимо, Git Bash не понимает скобки.

ЗЫ. Я согласен что этот вопрос дублирующим назвать можно, но ведь на изначальный вопрос так и не был дан вразумительный ответ, а в моем случае ответ от Nick Volynkin исчерпывающий.

Comment: дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/365314/178576 // но отметить дубликатом не могу, так как нет голосов за ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin плюсанул. К сожалению, я уже дал волю графомании и накатал ответ тут. )

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а вы заметили, насколько текущая редакция расходится с первой версией?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так я потому мгновенно и вспомнил, что где-то этот вопрос вот совсем недавно уже видел. отметил дубликатом.

Comment: @Jonny объясните пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду, полностью заменяя один вопрос другим?

Comment: @NickVolynkin тот вопрос для меня уже не актуален, удалить возможности нет

Comment: @Jonny как-то он быстро стал неактуальным, минуты 3 провисел всего... А возможность удалить свой вопрос - всегда есть.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я могу объединить вопросы.  Как думаете, какой делать основным?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а оно не «начнётся, как в [прошлый раз](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2872/178576)»? если нет, то логично основным оставить более старый вопрос. там хотя бы ссылка есть (под текстом «link text»).

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы конечно извините, но мне наверное виднее актуален для меня вопрос или нет.

Comment: в любом случае я получил ответ именно на то что меня интересовало за что благодарен  Nick Volynkin. по какому поводу поднялся кипишь я не понимаю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Синтаксис `<что-нибудь>` в технической документации как правило означает `<вместо этого слова в угловых скобках поместите сюда что-нибудь, имеющее смысл>`. Это как переменная, только в псевдокоде.

Git является контентно-адресуемой базой данных с высокоуровневым интерфейсом для осуществления собственно функций системы контроля версий. Это значит что все объекты данных доступны по некоторому имени-ключу. В качестве имени используется SHA1 от хранимых данных.

Программа Git никогда не создаст папку, буквально имеющую имя `.git/objects/<dir>`. В папке `.git/objects` находятся объекты внутреннего хранилища Git. 
Там создаются папки с именами из двух символов, эти символы - первые два символа из SHA1 от хранимых объектов. Оставшиеся 38 символов идут в имя файла.

Например, вот что хранится в репозитории проекта, над которым я прямо сейчас работаю. Я отсортировал результаты, чтобы показать, что в одну папку может помещаться несколько объектов:

```
find .git/objects/ -type f | sort | head
.git/objects/00/79240fb1519c1f54a140dabaab61a0868812f9
.git/objects/00/d722b5a26f7a9c6cefae8fffc5bfaf1621454f
.git/objects/05/bb369bb8ec8275763e3b14e0ff1f8926433b66
.git/objects/06/ec5c26beb527f457c1676193ed78413378193d
.git/objects/09/01f512887ad7a6c6253ec3d41a08a47cb98453
.git/objects/0c/90057804fc85288be478e7efad5539a712b5c6
.git/objects/0c/fddc95209d2b4b62fd0afaee21843da2366b17
.git/objects/0f/91d370683076b354a1aa0fb3b33e17a7aa8951
.git/objects/11/1fdf8d2bfe8d18b2b5fc319176da807bba05ef
.git/objects/12/04566e4266d8f50022300ce2c062e3b83079e1
```

В папке `.git/objects/00` хранятся два объекта данных. Если объединить имя папки и имя файла, получается, что их SHA1:

```
0079240fb1519c1f54a140dabaab61a0868812f9
00d722b5a26f7a9c6cefae8fffc5bfaf1621454f
```

Кстати, в учебнике по ссылке:

> Они сжаты и закодированы, поэтому просмотр их содержимого нам мало чем поможет.

Они просто не умеют просматривать. Всё очень просто:

```
git cat-file -t 0079240fb1519c1f54a140dabaab61a0868812f9
blob

git cat-file -p 0079240fb1519c1f54a140dabaab61a0868812f9 | less
(откроется содержимое файла, хранящегося в блобе)
```

Answer (score -1):

Экранируйте скобки

```
$ ls -C .git/objects/\<dir\>
ls: cannot access '.git/objects/<dir>': No such file or directory
```